# how to check for multiple strings in 'if-then-else-fi' in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file named 'testfile', which contains:

```
Computer Science   123 Congress Street,
Biology            2 New York Ave,
Graduate Center    1 New York Ave
```

And I have a *script* named 'search' as follows :

```
grep $* testfile
____________________                 # line 2
then echo "there is a match"         # message 1
else echo "no such department found" # message 2
fi
```

It should print "there is a match" for 'Computer Science', 'Biology' and 'Graduate Center' departments. And "no such department found" if none of the above departments.

So I am trying on #line2.
I have few questions regarding this :

(1) Is it possible to write 'grep' again inside of 'if' ? for e.g. can I write like this

> *if grep -q Biology "$testfile"*

. And if yes how can I test for all the strings(in this case 'departments') ?

(2) I know if I used only grep to find multiple strings I say

> *grep 'string1\|string2\|string3' PATH*

OR

> *egrep -w 'string1|string2' PATH*

But can I use this kind of format in if statement ? If yes , how ?

(3)
Is it possible to do this way? :

> *if ["$"=="Computer Science"] || ["$"=="Biology"] || ["$"=="Graduate Center"]*

Can anyone please help me to clarify my doubts ?

Answer (score 1):

The shell `if` statement takes an *arbitrary shell command*.  The `then` clause will be executed if that command, *whatever it is*, exits successfully; otherwise, the `else` clause will be executed.  So the answer to your first question is, yes, you can write `if grep -q 'pattern' testfile`, and you can also write `if egrep -qw 'string1|string2' testfile`, and you could even write `if perl -ne '(hundreds of lines of code here)' testfile` if you really wanted.

If I understand you correctly, your script takes a list of strings as arguments, and you want it to print "there is a match" if *all* of the strings match.  I would do that like this:

```
success=y
for arg in "$@"
do
  if grep -qF "$arg" "$testfile"
  then :
  else
    printf 'no match for %s\n' "$arg"
    success=n
  fi
done
if [ "$success" = "y" ]; then
  printf 'all strings matched\n'
fi
```

(The `then :; else ...` construct is the only *portable* way to invert the sense of a shell `if` statement; `if ! ...` is a bashism.  If you don't care about maximal portability, don't write a shell script; Perl is *more* likely to be available cross-platform than Bash is.  The `-q` and `-F` arguments to `grep` are not perfectly portable either, and neither is `printf`, but I haven't tripped over a system that didn't have them since the mid-2000s.)

Comment: I have only four lines as a basic format. So can I check for multiple strings in _'if grep -qF "$arg" "$testfile"'_ format ?                 In my case can I write like this _'if grep -qf 'ComputerScience\|Biology\|GraduationCenter' "$testfile"'_ ?

Comment: That doesn't do what you want on three counts: 1) `-f` and `-F` are different (as always, Unix is case sensitive); 2) assuming you meant `-F`, that would look for the *literal string* `ComputerScience\|Biology\|GraduationCenter`, with the backslashes and everything; 3) there *is* a way to look for multiple strings in one `grep` operation, `grep -qE 'ComputerScience|Biology|GraduationCenter' "$testfile"`, but it would report success if *any* of the three strings appeared in the file, not *all* of them.  There's no way to look for *all* strings in one `grep`.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "I have only four lines as a basic format".  You can put as much code in a shell script as you want.  [Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/s/autoconf) routinely generates shell scripts that are tens of thousands of lines long, and they work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this question using following script , it ran successfully. Initially I submitted my input string. And tried if that input string is matching with already present string in testfile. But aim was to use only one line of 'if' in between 'grep' and 'then'.
Please submit other answers also if any.

```
grep $* directory
echo -e "Hi, please type the word: \c "
read  word
echo "The word you entered is: $word"

if echo "Biology\|Computer Science\|Graduate Center MO" | grep -q "$word"
then 
echo "there is a match"
else 
echo "no such department found"
fi
```